# Replace Regina valve with Presta

Tags: innertube, valves, presta

I have recently bought an Italian bike that uses Regina valves and I need to replace one of the inner tubes. Since I don't live in Italy and can't find that kind of valve anywhere, I thought of using an inner tube with Presta valve instead since both are very similar.

Is there any reason why I should worry about replacing a Regina valve with Presta?

Comment: Wow, didn't know those even existed!

Comment: Well, from what little I read the Regina is kinda weird.  The two questions would be whether the hole in the rim is appropriately sized, and whether there is something "odd" about the rim (around the hole) vs a standard one used for Presta.  But people get away with using a Presta in place of a Schrader, even absent the bushings that *should* be used in that case, so I can't see a likely problem with the Regina hole, so long as it's large enough, but not as large as a Schrader.

Comment: The Presta valve fits, but it seems to be just a bit smaller than Regina (something around 0.1 mm since it can be moved more easily) and my main concern is that it will tear off.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about 0.1 mm -- theres no way you could get a grommet or something to adapt in that small of a space.

Comment: Apply a layer of electrician's tape around the base of the stem. It will keep the valve from rattling. I do that anyway with most Presta stems since they all seem to be a bit thinner than the holes in the rims.

Comment: http://www.schwalbetires.com/tech_info/valve say it looks like and is almost identical to a Presta valve, for those looking for a quick summary.

Answer (score 1):

Reginas and Prestas are really close in size, they can easily be interchanged. If you do find that it rattles in the larger hole on mixed surfaces, you can always use the threaded Presta nut, just don't crank it down too much. The Regina valve also has a metal seat, so before using the Presta, I would get a bit of emery cloth and make sure that there are no burrs on the inside of the valve hole - Presta tubes have a double rubber seat, so they are more fragile.